# Why is my Python timer class not working?

Tags: python, class, time, multiprocessing

I'v written my own class to measure the time of different parts of my script:

```
class SimulationTimer: 
    accumulated_elapsed_time = 0.0 
    def __init__(self):
        self._simulation_start_time = None
        self._simulation_stop_time = None

    def start(self):
        """start a new timer"""
        if self._simulation_start_time is not None:    # attribute
            raise TimeError(f"Timer is running.\n Use .stop() to stop it")

        self._simulation_start_time = time.perf_counter()  
    def stop(self):
        """stop the time and report the elsaped time"""
        if self._simulation_start_time is None:
            raise TimeError(f"Timer is not running.\n Use .start() to start it.")

        self._simulation_stop_time = time.perf_counter()
        elapsed_simulation_time = self._simulation_stop_time - self._simulation_start_time  
        self.accumulated_elapsed_time += elapsed_simulation_time # Isn't accumulating values of times. 

        self._simulation_start_time = None
        print(f"Elapsed time: {elapsed_simulation_time:0.10f} seconds")

    def get_accumulated_time(self):
        """ Return the elapsed time for later use"""
        return self.accumulated_elapsed_time
```

I'm trying to run a stochastic simulation multiple times on different cores and then plot `array1` against `array2` and measure the time it takes to run the simulation on the different cores that I'm running with `multiprocessing` `pool` method. With the following code:

```
def func(*args):
    t = SimulationTimer()
    t.start()
    Do stuff
    t.stop()
    print(f"Accumulated time: {t.get_accumulated_time():0.10f} seconds")
return array1, array2, t.accumulated_elapsed_time

array1, array2, accumulated_elapsed_time = gillespie_tau_leaping(start_state, LHS, stoch_rate, state_change_array)
```

Need the above line so array1 and array2 can be passed to the plotting function

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
with Pool() as p:
    pool_results = p.map(func, [*args])
    print(f"Total time:\n {sum(pool_results)}")

def gillespie_plot(array1, array2):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for i, label in enumerate(['Enzyme', 'Substrate', 'Enzyme-Substrate complex', 'Product']):
        ax.plot(array2, array1[:, i], label=label)
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()
    return fig

gillespie_plot(array1, array2)
```

But the `accumulate_elapsed_time` doesn't seem to be working. It's returning 4 separate times for each process and not accumulating the values of all the processes into to a total time.

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT: Its been suggested that edit `accumulated_elapsed_time = 0.0` from an instance to a `class` variable and to return `t.accumulated_elapsed_time`  from my function, which I've done but it still doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating 4 differente classes, with 4 differente variable.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
from simulationtimer import SimulationTimer


def func(proc_time):
    t = SimulationTimer()
    t.start()
    time.sleep(proc_time)
    t.stop()
    print(f"Accumulated time: {t.get_accumulated_time():0.10f} seconds")
    return t.get_accumulated_time()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool() as p:
        pool_results = p.map(func, [1, 1, 2])
        print('\nTotal time %s' % sum(pool_results))
```

Here is what you want:

```
def func(proc_time):
    t = SimulationTimer()
    t.start()
    time.sleep(proc_time)
    t.stop()
    print(f"Accumulated time: {t.get_accumulated_time():0.10f} seconds")
    array1 = 100
    array2 = 200
    return array1, array2, t.get_accumulated_time()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool() as p:
        pool_results = p.map(func, [1, 2, 3])

        total_time = 0
        for tuple_result in pool_results:
            total_time += tuple_result[2]

        print('\nTotal time %s' % total_time)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm just a bit unsure what the line: "time.sleep(proc_time)" does?

Comment: It is just a timeout in seconds to test your class.
proc_time get the number from the list: [1, 1, 2]
from the line: pool_results = p.map(func, [1, 1, 2])
Because i give him 3 elements the function "func" will run 3 times.

Comment: Okay, so get my original example working I'll need to return "t.get_accumulated_time" from my function and then sum the results from the pool?

Comment: Yeah, you can do that.

Comment: I've had a go at your suggestions but still having the same issues, see edits I've provided a few more details.

Comment: If you return more than One array it will return a list of tuple.
So when you do the sum you have to specify the 3rd item :  tuple_result[2]


...
    return array1, array2, t.get_accumulated_time()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool() as p:
        pool_results = p.map(func, [1, 2, 3])

        total_time = 0
        for tuple_result in pool_results:
            total_time += tuple_result[2]

        print('\nTotal time %s' % total_time)

Answer (score 2):

`accumulate_elapsed_time` is an instance variable, so every multiprocess is creating it anew. `accumulate_elapsed_time` needs to be a class variable.